# Suppress cascade delete annotation function when not needed in JPA CRUD

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, cascade

I have two entities Parent and Child that are in the bidirectional relationship like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Parent parent;  
}
```

Through annotation, when I delete an entry of Parent in the database, any child related to it will also be deleted through cascade.

However, there are cases where a Parent has no child; therefore, a cascade delete is not needed.

I want to differentiate my delete operation in terms of whether cascade is needed (e.g. was the deletion a simple delete or a delete that requires cascade).  Without making an explicit call on Parent to check if children are null, is there a way for JPA to automatically suppress the cascade annotation when not needed in a command like this one below?

```
this.parentRepository.delete(parentID);
```

Comment: Why do you think that in case when all (or any) children are `null` then hibernate will try to remove them?? There are nothing to remove...

Comment: @Cepr0 Hi, I'm aware of that.  My question is that for those Parents without Children is there a way to suppress the "cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE" part of the annotation explicitly because those Parents only need a simple delete?